# How to change default app to open magnet:// link without using a third-party UI app?

Tags: finder, applications, defaults

How to change default app to open ***magnet://*** link without using a third-party app?

I knew I maybe could use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) to do it but I am trying to figure out how to do it without installation of another app. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution after posting the question. A command line tool [duti](https://github.com/moretension/duti/) has a live github repo and can be installed easily with:

```
brew install duti
```

And then, check the current ***magnet://*** link setup:

```
$ duti -d magnet
com.bittorrent.uTorrent
```

Change and set another default app with the following cmd:

```
$ duti -s com.foo.foo magnet
```

That's all.

**MORE:**

To get a bundle_id of the app, there are two ways:

- If you know the app is a default app for an extension, you can do something like

```
$ duti -x html
Google Chrome.app
/Applications/Google Chrome.app
com.google.Chrome
```

- If you know the app name, you can do something like

```
$ osascript -e 'id of app "Google Chrome"'
com.google.Chrome
```